# Как настроить в .htaccess замену символа и редирект?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

Всем привет. Возник такой вопрос, можно ли в файле .htaccess сделать замену символа в адресной строке и редирект, и если да, то как?
Задача следующая:
Предположим есть сайт, у него динамические страницы формата: “mysite.ru/page_one”,  “mysite.ru/page_two_lvl”
Ну и т.п, т.е. адреса с нижним подчеркиванием. При реорганизации сайта страницы были изменены (то же имя но вместо нижнего подчеркивания дефис),так как пользователи могут переходить по старой ссылке (с нижнем подчеркиванием) возможно ли заменить все нижние подчеркивания на дефис и редиректнуть пользователя со страницы с нижним подчеркиванием на новую страницу с дефисом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на уровне [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) это сделать нельзя, но можно это сделать на уровне приложения:

```
<?php
$redirect = str_replace('_', '-', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header("Location: $redirect"); 
exit;
```

Если есть еще параметры, то добавить к $redirect еще $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].